# Which orbits of a separable representation of the infinite unitary group are closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-groups

Consider a separable irreducible unitary representation of $U(\mathcal{H})$ in the Hilbert space $V$. Assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is separable. My question is the following:

> Is it true that all orbits of
>   $U(\mathcal{H})$ in
>   $\mathbb{P}\mathcal{V}$ are closed? If
>   not, are there any conditions for
>   given state
>   $[v]\in\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$ that
>   guarantee that the orbit
>   $[U(\mathcal{H}).v]$ is closed?

Motivation: I want to generalize a well known result from the theory of representations of compact semisimple Lie groups that states that the orbit through the highest weight vector in $\mathbb{P}V$  is characterized by a certain a quadric. Due to the structure of separable representations of $U(\mathcal{H})$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90006/is-there-schur-weyl-duality-for-infinite-dimensional-unitary-group)) one can hope that the similar characterization is valid for orbits through "highest weight vectors" in these representations. In order to complete the proof I need to know that orbits through these highest weight vectors are closed. I was able to prove closedness for "highest weight orbits" in cases that are most interesting from the physical perspective: $V=\bigwedge^L\mathcal{H}$ and $V=Sym^L(\mathcal{H})$ but I am not able to cope with the general case.